# Multiple values on each line with dotchart in R

Tags: r

I have the following input file for R:

```
car    1
car    2 
car    3 
car2   1 
car2   2 
car2   3
```

I then use the following commands to plot my graph:

> autos_data <- read.table("~/Documents/R/test.txt", header=F)
>
> dotchart(autos_data$V2,autos_data$V1)

But this plots each car and car2 value on a new line, how can I plot the chart so that all the car values are on one line and all the car2 values are on another line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there's just no way to do that with base `dotchart`.

However, if a lattice `dotplot` suits your needs as well, you can just do:

```
library(lattice)
dotplot(V1~V2, data=autos_data)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Note that you can add dots to a dotchart with [?points](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/points.html), so this *can* be done in base R with a little bit of data management.  Here's how it could be done:

```
autos_data = read.table(text="car    1
car    2 
car    3 
car2   1 
car2   2 
car2   3", header=F)

aData2 = autos_data[!duplicated(autos_data[,1]),]

dotchart(aData2[,2], labels=aData2[,1], 
         xlim=c(min(autos_data[,2]), max(autos_data[,2])))
points(autos_data[,2] , autos_data[,1])
```

[image]

@Josh O'Brien's lattice solution is more elegant, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `ggplot2` solution

```
qplot(V1, V2, data=autos_data) + coord_flip()
```

[image]